# In Gstreamer while playing the pipeline in iOS 8, and after entering background and returning foreground pipeline doesnt work :(?

Tags: ios, gstreamer, ios8-extension

-Actually i downloaded the sample tutorial for gstreamer from the link,

http://cgit.freedesktop.org/~slomo/gst-sdk-tutorials/

git://people.freedesktop.org/~slomo/gst-sdk-tutorials

- Now i had modified the following code in the tutorial 3,

  ```
  -(void) app_function
   {
  GstBus *bus;
  GSource *bus_source;
  GError *error = NULL;

  GST_DEBUG ("Creating pipeline");

  pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("e-pipeline");


  /* Create our own GLib Main Context and make it the default one */
  context = g_main_context_new ();
  g_main_context_push_thread_default(context);

  /* Build pipeline */
  // pipeline = gst_parse_launch("videotestsrc ! warptv ! videoconvert ! autovideosink", &error);


  source = gst_element_factory_make("udpsrc", "source");

  g_object_set( G_OBJECT ( source),   "port", 8001, NULL );

  GstCaps *caps;

  caps = gst_caps_new_simple ("application/x-rtp",
                              "encoding-name", G_TYPE_STRING, "H264",
                              "payload", G_TYPE_INT, 96,
                              "clock-rate", G_TYPE_INT, 90000,
                              NULL);

  g_object_set (source, "caps", caps, NULL);




  rtp264depay = gst_element_factory_make ("rtph264depay", "rtph264depay");
  h264parse = gst_element_factory_make ("h264parse", "h264parse");
  vtdec = gst_element_factory_make ("vtdec", "vtdec");
  glimagesink  = gst_element_factory_make ("glimagesink", "glimagesink");

  gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN(pipeline), source,  rtp264depay, h264parse, vtdec, glimagesink, NULL);




  if (error) {
      gchar *message = g_strdup_printf("Unable to build pipeline: %s", error->message);
      g_clear_error (&error);
      [self setUIMessage:message];
      g_free (message);
      return;
  }

  /* Set the pipeline to READY, so it can already accept a window handle */
  gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_READY);

  video_sink = gst_bin_get_by_interface(GST_BIN(pipeline), GST_TYPE_VIDEO_OVERLAY);
  if (!video_sink) {
      GST_ERROR ("Could not retrieve video sink");
      return;
  }
  gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle(GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY(video_sink), (guintptr) (id) ui_video_view);

  /* Instruct the bus to emit signals for each received message, and connect to the interesting signals */
  bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);
  bus_source = gst_bus_create_watch (bus);
  g_source_set_callback (bus_source, (GSourceFunc) gst_bus_async_signal_func, NULL, NULL);
  g_source_attach (bus_source, context);
  g_source_unref (bus_source);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (bus), "message::error", (GCallback)error_cb, (__bridge void *)self);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (bus), "message::state-changed", (GCallback)state_changed_cb, (__bridge void *)self);
  gst_object_unref (bus);

  /* Create a GLib Main Loop and set it to run */
  GST_DEBUG ("Entering main loop...");
  main_loop = g_main_loop_new (context, FALSE);
  [self check_initialization_complete];
  g_main_loop_run (main_loop);
  GST_DEBUG ("Exited main loop");
  g_main_loop_unref (main_loop);
  main_loop = NULL;

  /* Free resources */
  g_main_context_pop_thread_default(context);
  g_main_context_unref (context);
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (pipeline);

  return;
  ```

  }

-Now am running the application in the ipad,and Application starts playing.

- Now am entering background and returning to foreground the 
  Gstreamer streaming updates are not visible in the UI,but in the xcode's network usage I could see the packets receiving....:(

Thanks in advance....iOS GEEKS....

Comment: i also face the same issue in Gstreamer in iPhone. please post if you find solution. :(

Comment: pipeline = gst_parse_launch("udpsrc host=192.168.7.45 port=5000 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink sync=false text-overlay=false", &error);  Error Pipeline error Unable to build pipeline: no element "udpsrc"

Comment: plz explain which extra varible you use and there type like , source, rtp264depay etc

Comment: Hii 

I am new to Gstremer and i am running a demo
// pipeline = gst_parse_launch("videotestsrc ! warptv ! videoconvert ! autovideosink", &error);

The above line in uncommened in my side and i got the error - "no element is found for warptv" ? do you have any solution 

Please help me
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update: Get UDP to work.**

After further investigation I got UDP h264 streaming to work on linux (PC x86) but the principle should be the same on IOS (specifically **avdec_h264** (used on PC) has to be replaced by **vtdec**).

Key differences between the TCP and UDP pipelines:

**Server side:**

- IP : The 1st element which confused me between UDP and TCP server sides : On **UDP server**, the IP address specified on the **udpsink** element is the **client side IP**, i.e.
  `gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! udpsink host=$CLIENTIP port=5000`

While on the **TCP server** side, the IP is the one of the **server side** (host parameter on tcpserversink) i.e.
`gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=$SERVERIP port=5000`

- Video stream payload/format: In order for the client to be able to detect the format and size of the frames, the **TCP server** side makes use of **gdppay**, a **payloader** element, in its pipeline. On the **client side** the opposite element, a de-payloader is used **gdpdepay** in order to be able to read the received frames.
  i.e.

gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! **gdppay** ! tcpserversink host=$SERVERIP port=5000

The UDP server side does **not** use the gdpay element, it leaves the client side to use a **CAPS** on its udpsink see below in the client side differences.

**Client side**

- IP: The **UDP** client does **NOT** need any IP specified.
  While the **TCP** client side needs the **server IP** (host parameter on tcpclientsrc) i.e.
  `gst-launch-1.0 -v tcpclientsrc host=$SERVERIP port=5000 ! gdpdepay ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false enable-last-buffer=false`
- Video stream payload/format:like mentionned in the previous paragraph, the TCP server side uses payloader **gdppay** while the client side uses a de-payloader to recognize the format and size of the frames.

Instead the **UDP** client has to explicitely specify it using a **caps** on its udpsrc element i.e.
`CAPS='application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96'`

gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 caps=$CAPS ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false enable-last-buffer=false`

**How to specify the caps** : it is a bit hacky but it works:
run your UDP server, with the verbose option **-v** i.e.
`gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! udpsink host=$CLIENTIP port=5000`

You'll get the following log:

`Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, parsed=(boolean)true, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, codec_data=(buffer)01640028ffe1000e27640028ac2b402802dd00f1226a01000428ee1f2c
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0.GstPad:src: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)"J2QAKKwrQCgC3QDxImo\=\,KO4fLA\=\=", payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)3473549335, timestamp-offset=(uint)257034921, seqnum-offset=(uint)12956
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)"J2QAKKwrQCgC3QDxImo\=\,KO4fLA\=\=", payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)3473549335, timestamp-offset=(uint)257034921, seqnum-offset=(uint)12956
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, parsed=(boolean)true, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, codec_data=(buffer)01640028ffe1000e27640028ac2b402802dd00f1226a01000428ee1f2c
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0: timestamp = 257034921
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0: seqnum = 12956
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...`

Now copy the caps starting with **caps = application/x-rtp**
This is the one specifying the rtp stream format. As far as I know the one that really is mandatory to get the UDP client to recognize the rtp stream content and then initialise the playing.

To wrap it up and avoid confusion, find complete command line examples below, using raspivid with a Raspberry pi. if you want to try it ( on linux )

**UDP**

- Server: `raspivid -t 0 -w 1280 -h 720 -fps 25 -b 2500000 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! udpsink host=$CLIENTIP port=5000`
- Client: 
  `CAPS='application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96'
  gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 caps=$CAPS ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false enable-last-buffer=false`

**TCP**

- Server: `raspivid -t 0 -w 1280 -h 720 -fps 25 -b 2500000 -o - | gst-launch-0.10 -v fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=$SERVERIP port=5000`
- Client: `gst-launch-1.0 -v tcpclientsrc host=$SERVERIP port=5000 ! gdpdepay ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false enable-last-buffer=false`

Note: Raspivid could easily be be replaced by a simple h264 file using **cat** i.e. `cat myfile.h264 | gst-launch...`

Comment: I am facing some error when creating pipeline in Gstreamer   Pipeline error Unable to build pipeline: no element "udpsrc"   Pls specify what is correct syntax

Answer (score 1):

I recently tried getting a live streaming working from a RaspberryPi to IOS8 using hardware h264 decoding, using the Apple VideoToolBox API thru the "vtdec" gstreamer plugin.

I looked at many tutorials, namely from braincorp (https://github.com/braincorp/gstreamer_ios_tutorial)

and 
Sebastian Dröge:
http://cgit.freedesktop.org/~slomo/gst-sdk-tutorials/

I got the latter one to work, tutorial 3 modified:

- **Server pipeline** on **RaspberryPi** using pi Camera and Raspivid + gstreamer:
  **raspivid -t 0 -w 1280 -h 720 -fps 25 -b 2500000 -p 0,0,640,480 -o - | gst-launch-0.10 -v fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=ServerIPRaspberryPi port=any_port_on_Rpi**
- **client** side pipeline one **IOS 8** device:
  **tcpclientsrc host=ServerIPRaspberryPi port=any_port_on_Rpi ! gdpdepay ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! vtdec ! glimagesink**

or the same with instead of glimagesink **autovideosink**.

This solution works and several clients can be used simultaneously. I tried getting udpsink to work instead of tcpserversink, but not luck so far it never worked.

===**IMPORTANT**===
Also the factory way using **gst_element_factory_make() + gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN(pipeline), ...)** never worked.
Instead I used the **pipeline = gst_parse_launch(...)** method.

So in our case, on the IOS client side:
**pipeline = gst_parse_launch("tcpclientsrc host=172.19.20.82 port=5000 ! gdpdepay ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! vtdec ! autovideosink", &error);**

Possible reason: There is a page documenting differences, and how to port code from gstreamer **0.10** and **1.0**: 
http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/chapter-porting-1.0.html

We noted that while using the **"factory method"** there were various elements of the pipeline missing depending on whether we were using gstreamer **1.0** or **0.1** i.e. **trph264depay** or **avdec_h264** (used on other platforms i.e. linux client side) to decode h264 instead of **IOS** specific **vtdec**).

We could hardly get all elements together using the **Factory** method but we managed using the **"gst_parse_launch()"** function without any problems, on IOS and linux.

So in conclusion, while we haven't tested and got the **UDP** sink to work, then try the **TCP** way using **tcpclientsrc** element instead, get it working, then only once it works, try find your way to **udp** and pls let us know if you get to an end.

Best Regards, hope this helps many of you.

Romain S